# Python TFLearn can't save to a single model.tfl file

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-learning, model, tflearn

Here is my code:

```
try:
     model.load("./model.tfl")
except:
     tensorflow.compat.v1.reset_default_graph()

     net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, len(training[0])])
     net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 8)
     net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 8)
     net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 8)
     net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, len(output[0]), activation="softmax")
     net = tflearn.regression(net)

     model = tflearn.DNN(net)

     model.fit(training, output, n_epoch=1000, batch_size=8, show_metric=True)
     model.save("model.tfl")
```

My issue is that whenever I save the model, it results in 3 files being made:

- model.tfl.data-00000-of-00001
- model.tfl.index
- model.tfl.meta

How would I go about saving these to one file? Or how would I load the model from these files?

Comment: Try saving the model using '.model' extension. i.e: 

```model.save("model_name.model");```

For loading the model:
```model.load("model_name.model")```

Comment: @MDBillalHossain I've already tried that, no matter what I make the file extension or name, it still does the same thing